# Find the day, hour and minute difference between dd/mm/yyyy and did/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: date, time

I am looking for getting Difference between two time formats in Oracle dd/mm/yyyy and did/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.
I need the day, hour difference and minute difference